# Firebase Firestore .get() not returning expected data

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

This code segement always returns "Keep going!":

```
const scoreAsInt = parseInt(firebase.firestore().collection("users").doc(user.uid).collection("scores").doc("test").get("testScore"));

const targetScoreAsInt = parseInt(firebase.firestore().collection("users").doc(user.uid).get("target"));

  if(scoreAsInt === targetScoreAsInt || scoreAsInt > targetScoreAsInt) {
    window.alert("You reached your target!!");
  } else {
    window.alert("Keep going!");
  }
```

`firebase.firestore().collection("users").doc(user.uid).collection("scores").doc("test").get("testScore")` and `firebase.firestore().collection("users").doc(user.uid).get("target")` should both be strings in firestore that look like numbers (such as string "1000"). I want to use `parseInt()` to get these two data fields as integers and perform comparisons on them, but it always alerts "Keep going!" even when it shouldn't.

Additionally I tried debugging by trying this:

```
console.log(firebase.firestore().collection("users").doc(user.uid).collection("scores").doc("test").get("testScore"));
console.log(firebase.firestore().collection("users").doc(user.uid).get("target"));
console.log("......");
console.log(scoreAsInt);
console.log(targetScoreAsInt);
```

console returned this:

> Promise {   "_U": 0,   "_V": 0,   "_W": null,   "_X": null, }
>
> Promise {   "_U": 0,   "_V": 0,   "_W": null,   "_X": null, }
>
> ......
>
> NaN
>
> NaN

What am I doing wrong here with trying to retrieve my Firestore data to perform comparisons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firestore returns promises, so you either need to put this into a function which supports async/await or use promises.  Also, by fetching the same document twice, this will cost you for 2 reads.

Using async/await...

```
async function getScores() {

  try {
    const db = firebase.firestore();
    const scoreDoc = await db.doc(`users/${user.id}/scores/test`).get();
    const {testScore, target} = scoresDoc.data();
  
    const scoreAsInt = parseInt(testScore);
    const targetAsInt = parseInt(target);

    if(scoreAsInt === targetScoreAsInt || scoreAsInt > targetScoreAsInt) {
      window.alert("You reached your target!!");
    } else {
      window.alert("Keep going!");
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
}
```

...or with promises...

```
const db = firebase.firestore();
return db.doc(`users/${user.id}/scores/test`).get().then((scoresDoc) => {
  const {testScore, target} = scoresDoc.data();

  const scoreAsInt = parseInt(testScore);
  const targetAsInt = parseInt(target);

  if(scoreAsInt === targetScoreAsInt || scoreAsInt > targetScoreAsInt) {
    window.alert("You reached your target!!");
  } else {
    window.alert("Keep going!");
  }
}).catch((err) => {
  console.error(err);
});
```

Comment: Hey so I just did `scoresDoc.data()["testScore"]` and I got what I needed, thanks anyways!

Comment: This also works.  It's just not as efficient

Comment: Did using Promises or Async/Await fix your issue?  If so, please can you mark my answer as accepted?